# Show Debug on production for admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to override env data

I overridethe mail service like this

```
config(['mail.host' => $emails_data->host]);
        config(['mail.username' => $emails_data->username]);
        config(['mail.password' => $emails_data->password]);
        (new MailServiceProvider(app()))->register();
```

but if I do it for the app   it don't work ?

```
config(['app.debug' => true]);
        (new AppServiceProvider (app()))->register();
```

How can I override the env data while the app is running ?

---

I'm trying to add it in Middleware

```
class DebugBar
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        app('debugbar')->disable();

        if ( Session::get('shop') == 'name' ) {
            // register new config value
            config(['app.debug' => true]);
            (new AppServiceProvider (app()))->register();

             //enable debuger
            app('debugbar')->enable();

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: the .env file should not stay on the server. On the server you should use config files

Comment: you can do that, but the real question is, where are you trying to do it?

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro  even if I used  .htaccess to prevent uesers to access it ? ?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy  I'm trying to add it in Middleware  I added example above

Comment: @ahmad to override .env file you have to use laravel config files, not .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables cannot modified by `env()` or `config()` helpers.

You need to use `putenv()` PHP function to overwrite environment variables, e.g. `putenv("APP_DEBUG=false");`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php

Comment: Yes, replace `config(['app.debug' => true]);` to `putenv("APP_DEBUG=false");`

Answer (score -1):

add next on file "app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php"

```
    if( env('APP_DEBUG') ) {
    \Debugbar::enable();
}else{
    \Debugbar::disable();
}
```